# How to use wildcard subdomains with a Windows Azure application?

Tags: azure, subdomain, wildcard

Can someone explain me how to configure dyndns to obtain cname wildcard in azure domain?

I already bought a domain and the custom dns service, can you please give me some help?

More info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/8c6cac50-2977-4b61-aa32-443013d66ef3

Comment: What "custom dns service"do you own?  configuration/ability depends on that

Comment: As another option, here's a [blog post](http://www.stratospher.es/blog/post/wildcard-subdomains-in-windows-azure) I put together about using Route 53 to support wildcard subdomains with Azure. Hope that helps. -adam

Comment: @AdamHoffman - would you mind taking a peek RE an Azure Website config?  I'm using your article but I'm at a blocker, any help would be much appreciated:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832484/wildcard-subdomains-with-azure-websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution, i just needed to wait for dyndns to propagate the domain. It takes 48h to have the url working.